# Existence of nearby spectrum

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $A$ be a bounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$. Suppose that there exist $\lambda,c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $u\neq 0$ in $H$ such that

$$\left\|(A-\lambda)u\right\|_H\leq c\|u\|_H.$$

**Question:** Does there exist $\lambda'$ in the spectrum of $A$ such that $|\lambda-\lambda'|\leq c$?

*Thoughts:* If $A$ is a diagonal matrix I can see why this is true, but I'd like to prove it for general $A$.

Comment: I guess you want $u \neq 0$? Also, even for a diagonal matrix, you only get $|\lambda -\lambda'|\geq c$, not $<c$. And yes, this is true. One way to see this is via the spectral theorem.

Comment: Yes you are right (assuming you mean $\leq c$?). If you write an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: $A -\lambda$ is generally a bounded operator, you don't have to require $\lambda, c, u$ to fulfill it

Comment: @Pazu But that's not the question. The content of the question is whether the existence of a single $u$ satisfying that condition with $c$ as the bound is enough to ensure there's $\lambda'$ within $c$ of $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sigma(A)$ denote the spectrum of $A$. Suppose to the contrary that $\left|\lambda-\lambda'\right|>c$ for all $\lambda'\in\sigma(A)$.

Then the contradiction follows from the spectral theorem, by which we have

$$\left\|(A-\lambda)u\right\|_H^2=\int_{\sigma(A)} (\lambda-\lambda')^2\,d\mu_u(\lambda’)>c^2\int_{\sigma(A)}d\mu_u(\lambda’)=c^2\left\|u\right\|_H^2.$$

Here $d\mu_u$ is the unique positive measure associated to $A$ and $u$ satisfying the property that for all $\varphi\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$,
$$\langle\varphi(A)u,u\rangle_H,$$
$\varphi(A)$ being defined by the continuous functional calculus.